# Powerpoint - VBA - Put selected text into square bracket

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create a macro that will work on powerpoint to put the selected text into square brackets. I found a code working on Excel but I need to adapt it for PowperPoint. However, after few tries I can not figure how to correct it. 
Could you help me with that ?

```
Sub other_Brackets() ' Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + T
Dim Form As String
Set def = Selection
For Each bracket In Selection
    bracket.Select
    Form = ActiveCell.Formula
    If Left(Form, 1) = "[" Or Right(Form, 1) = "]" Then
        If Left(Form, 1) = "[" Then
            Form = Right(Form, Len(Form) - 1)
        End If
        If Right(Form, 1) = "]" Then
            Form = Left(Form, Len(Form) - 1)
        End If
        ActiveCell.Formula = Form
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "[" & Form & "]"
    End If
Next
Application.GoTo def
End Sub
```

Exemple : if I select in Powerpoint "thisisatext" and I activate the macro the result will be "[thisisatext]"; and if I am still on the selection "[thisisatext]" and I activate the macro the result will be "thisisatext".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue (there are more than one) is that the excel code is working on the active cell. On powerpoint, you can just use ActiveWindow.Selection

This should work:

```
Sub other_Brackets() ' Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + T
Dim selectedText As String
Dim replacedText As String
selectedText = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
If Left(selectedText, 1) = "[" Or Right(selectedText, 1) = "]" Then
    replacedText = Right(selectedText, Len(selectedText) - 1)
    replacedText = Left(replacedText, Len(replacedText) - 1)
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange = replacedText
Else
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange = "[" & selectedText & "]"
End If
```

End Sub